# Is there a way to find out what each argument of attribute does?

Tags: attributes, magento-2.1.2

What i want to know is that exactly how much arguments an attribute has and **how can we know what each argument does ?**

**e.g.** Consider adding an attribue for customer.

**Here's the code where you can find some of the parameters.**

```
$customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, "verified_buyer",  array(
            "type"     => "integer",
            "backend"  => "",
            "label"    => "Verified Buyer",
            "input"    => "checkbox",
            "source"   => "",
            "visible"  => true,
            "required" => false,
            "default" => 0,
            "frontend" => "",
            "unique"     => false,
            "note"       => "",
            "sort_order"       => "100"


        ));
```

Let me know if there is any resource/article about it.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you checked addAttribute function definition? you will have idea what are required input

Comment: Actually, I tried but was not able to track the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an attribute description in the `Magento\Eav` module:

```
app/code/Magento/Eav
```

The main model for the attribute is `Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute`. The `addAttribute` method is defined in the `Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup` class. All properties was mapped to the eav attribute columns in the `Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\PropertyMapper`:

```
/**
 * Map input attribute properties to storage representation
 *
 * @param array $input
 * @param int $entityTypeId
 * @return array
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
 */
public function map(array $input, $entityTypeId)
{
    return [
        'attribute_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'attribute_model'),
        'backend_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'backend'),
        'backend_type' => $this->_getValue($input, 'type', 'varchar'),
        'backend_table' => $this->_getValue($input, 'table'),
        'frontend_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'frontend'),
        'frontend_input' => $this->_getValue($input, 'input', 'text'),
        'frontend_label' => $this->_getValue($input, 'label'),
        'frontend_class' => $this->_getValue($input, 'frontend_class'),
        'source_model' => $this->_getValue($input, 'source'),
        'is_required' => $this->_getValue($input, 'required', 1),
        'is_user_defined' => $this->_getValue($input, 'user_defined', 0),
        'default_value' => $this->_getValue($input, 'default'),
        'is_unique' => $this->_getValue($input, 'unique', 0),
        'note' => $this->_getValue($input, 'note'),
        'is_global' => $this->_getValue(
            $input,
            'global',
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL
        )
    ];
}
```

I can't answer all your questions, but I think this information will help you to find the correct way.